# Setting info-window offset for agm snazzy-info-window

Tags: angular-google-maps, snazzymaps

I'm using agm and agm snazzy-info window. Since the marker I'm using is small, the info window is too far from the marker.
Looking at snazzy-info-window docs -
https://github.com/atmist/snazzy-info-window#offset seems like they let you set the offset from the marker. It seems like agm snazzy-info-window hide this option, see https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-snazzy-info-window/.

Is there any way to control the offset using agm snazzy-info window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, [`offset` property](https://github.com/atmist/snazzy-info-window#offset) according to [angular-google-maps repository](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/blob/master/packages/snazzy-info-window/directives/snazzy-info-window.ts) is not exposed via `AgmSnazzyInfoWindow` component.  One option to circumvent this limitation would be to introduce a custom component which *extends* `AgmSnazzyInfoWindow` component and supports to specify `offset` property, for example:

```
import {
  Component,
  AfterViewInit,
  Input
} from "@angular/core";
import { AgmSnazzyInfoWindow } from "@agm/snazzy-info-window";

@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
  selector: 'my-info-window',
  template:
    "<div #outerWrapper><div #viewContainer></div></div><ng-content></ng-content>"
})
export class MyInfoWindowComponent extends AgmSnazzyInfoWindow
  implements AfterViewInit {

   /**
   * A custom padding size around the content of the info window.
   */
  @Input() offset: {top: string, left: string};

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    super.ngAfterViewInit();
    this._snazzyInfoWindowInitialized.then(() => {
      this._nativeSnazzyInfoWindow._opts.offset = this.offset;
    });
  }
}
```

Now offset could be specified like this:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="center.lat" [longitude]="center.lng">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="center.lat" [longitude]="center.lng">
    <my-info-window
      [offset]="{
        top: '-60px',
        left: '0px'
      }"
    >
      <ng-template>
        Phoenix
      </ng-template>
    </my-info-window>
  </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v6txwv)

Comment: Great solution here. I needed to use the underlying property `edgeOffset` which isn't included in @agm/snazzy-info-window either. This worked well. Thanks!